# Extraxting data (numbers) from xlsx cells (5400 cells) and puting them to list object in Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, list, openpyxl, xlsx

I have a problem with extracting data form xlsx file. I have to say that i am beginer and i recently start working with python. This is the code that i got:

```
import openpyxl

random_nums = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='/home/kre/Desktop/File/File_11_2019.xlsx', data_only=True)
wb_print = random_nums.active

print(wb_print)

for row in wb_print.iter_rows(min_row=0, max_col=0, max_row=5400):
    for cell in row:
        print(wb_print["A1"].value)      

sheet = random_nums.get_sheet_by_name
```

The output is just one cell, A1 in this case but i need the whole range of 20 cols and 5400 rows...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you add an example about your xlsx?...maybe with pandas is more easy to hand

Comment: I need to analyze large amount of random numbers in Python... 108 000 to be exact.

Need to put them in a list and count for how many times number appears, they are in range 1-80...

Comment: can you add an example here?...www.transferbigfiles.com

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: ***"put them in a list"***: `list(ws.iter_rows(values_only=True))`

Comment: What do you expect `wb_print['A1']` to do? It will give you the same result for every row, but only for columns in the worksheet: the minimum is 1.